# Как грамотно задать элементу событие onclick

Tags: javascript

Обратите внимание на html разметку, меня интересует как правильно  задать onclick элементу.
Сделал три варианта, они все работают. В силу того, что я недавно начал изучение JS, я не могу понять какой из этих вариантов более грамотный.

```js
function one(){
alert('Do you like, what you see?')
}

function two(){
alert('1000-7')
}

let three = document.querySelector('.block3');

three.onclick = function (){
alert('It gets bigger, when i pull on it');
}
```

```css
.block1{
margin-top:10px;
padding:10px;
border: 3px solid black;
}

.block2{
margin-top:10px;
padding:10px;
border: 3px solid black;
}

.block3{
margin-top:10px;
padding:10px;
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class ="block1" onclick ="one()"> 1 вариант </div>  <!-- 1 вариант  -->
<div class ="block2" onclick = two() > 2 вариант </div>  <!-- 2 вариант  -->
<div class ="block3"> 3 вариант </div>                   <!-- 3 вариант  -->
```

Comment: чем отличается 1 от 2?

Comment: На самом деле ни один из вариантов не является правильным (в современном мире)

Comment: А что нужно использовать?
Всплытие?

Comment: можно его. в целом сейчас слушатели навешиваются через addEventListener. Использовать делегирование или нет - уже дело десятое

Comment: так в чём разница 1 и 2 варианта?

Comment: в 1 варианте есть скобки, а во втором нет скобок. Почему без скобок второй вариант работает ?
И что такое слушатели?

Comment: в обоих вариантах нарисованы скобки

Comment: слушатели: https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener    ...... https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener .....

Comment: слушатели это click, mouseover и keydown, то есть методы, которые позволяют нам взаимодействовать с элементами на html разметке, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [всплытие](https://learn.javascript.ru/bubbling-and-capturing), чтоб событие могло срабатывать на динамически созданных элементах.

```js
const message = msg => {
  switch (msg) {
    case `one`:
      return `Do you like, what you see?`;
    case `two`:
      return `1000-7`;
    case `three`:
      return `It gets bigger, when i pull on it`;
    default:
      return `Ошибка`;
  }
}

addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  const $target = e.target.closest(`.block`);
  if (!$target) return;

  alert(message($target.dataset.alert));
})
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" data-alert="one"> 1 вариант </div>
<div class="block" data-alert="two"> 2 вариант </div>
<div class="block" data-alert="three"> 3 вариант </div>
<div class="block"> неопознанный вариант </div>
```

Comment: Зачем тогда onclick, есть всплытие гораздо лучше него?

Comment: Как всплытию задать несколько разных сообщений при клике на разные блоки?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький "Зачем тогда onclick" - исторические причины, обратная совместимость и лишний способ задать обработчик никому не повредит. "Как всплытию задать несколько разных сообщений при клике на разные блоки?" - в ответе в `$target` содержится нужный блок, можете применять к нему условия по вкусу.

Comment: Я не могу понять как  это реализовать. Если вам не составить труда, то не могли бы вы пожалуйста в своём ответе показать вывод трех разных сообщений при клике на эти три блока. Чтобы результат получился как у меня в исходном коде.

Comment: @Хмельни́цький исправил ответ.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ =) А если я хочу хранить сообщения в JS коде, а не в html разметке, то как быть?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький ну так заведите себе функцию, что вы как маленький. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Ух ты, вот это чудеса =) Спс за ответ =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130456/discussion-between-nazarpunk-and-).

Comment: слушатели это click, mouseover и keydown, то есть методы, которые позволяют нам взаимодействовать с элементами на html разметке, верно?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький есть [события](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events), на которые нужно каким-то образом реагировать. Для этого придуманы [слушатели](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), которые позволяют выполнять код по наступлению какого либо события.

Answer (score 0):

По клику был дан ответ, но я объясню.

```
Инициализация переменной: const переменная = document.функцияВыборки(Вызов с нужным параметром); 


init: const buttonRight = document.querySelector('.buttonRight');
```

Следующим шагом мы должны подписаться на событие у нашего элемента.

```
:exp: элемент.функцияПодпискиНаСобытие(нужный параметр-событие () => вызов функции, которая отработает в момент события);  


:exp: buttonRight.addEventListener('event', (e) => main(e));
```

Уточню, что в данном случае мы слушаем событие у фрагмента типа  element.

Сейчас при нажатии на нашу кнопку, которую мы получили ранее сработает event, когда он будет выполнен, мы вызываем анонимную функцию, которая в свою очередь вернет главную функцию, она же в свою очередь сначала вызывается.

Есть более устаревшая/ситуативная вариация с записью.

```
:exp: buttonRight.addEventListener('click', (e) => {console.log(e);}); 
:exp: buttonRight.addEventListener('click', fc);  
:exp: buttonRight.addEventListener('click', function() {});
```

1. Пишем функцию внутри обработчика.
2. Вызываем функцию внутри обработчика без параметров.
3. Пишем не стрелочную функцию внутри обработчика.

Теперь решим вашу задачу:

```js
const DATAONE = "one";
const DATATWO = "two";
const DATATHEREE = "three";

addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  const block = e.target.closest(`.block`);

  if (!block) {
    return alert("Error");
  }

  const { alert: dataset } = block.dataset;
  if (DATAONE === dataset) {
    return alert(DATAONE);
  } else if (DATATWO === dataset) {
    return alert(DATATWO);
  } else if (DATATHEREE === dataset) {
    return alert(DATATHEREE);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="block" data-alert="one"> 1 вариант </div>
<div class="block" data-alert="two"> 2 вариант </div>
<div class="block" data-alert="three"> 3 вариант </div>
```

Comment: слушатели это click, mouseover и keydown, то есть методы, которые позволяют нам взаимодействовать с элементами на html разметке, верно?

Comment: В вашем случае `alert("Error")`  будет вызван при клике куда угодно кроме `.block`.

Comment: Ну, событий на самом деле много. Но важно не какое событие, а какой принцип работы подобных слушателей. Очень крутая практика, если вы изобретете свой собственный вариант и событие при котором вариант сработает. А между прочем - это не так просто.